# Importing shapefiles into CartoDB

Tags: shapefile, carto

I'm trying to make a survey of all regions in Sweden for an article that me and my colleague are working on. When I'm trying to import the shapefiles into CartoDB it says " Unfortunately this file extension is not allowed ". Im guessing the reason is that i got the free version.

Is it possible to work this out in some way?

Answer (score 1):

CartoDB expects shapefiles to be imported in a .zip package that contains, at least:

- file.shp
- file.shx
- file.dbf
- file.prj

Make sure you have included all those files in your .zip package, and that the extension of it is lowercase (.zip and not .ZIP)

Comment: And there's a tutorial on how to do this here: http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/import_shapefile_in_cartodb/